# How to break out of a for loop inside a recursive function and return in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, recursion, return

I'm trying to compare keys of two objects, values of properties don't matter.

```js
var obj1 = {
    foo: {
        abc: "foo.abc",
    },
    bar: {
        aaa: {
            bbb: "bar.aaa.bbb" // <-- difference
        }
    }
};

var obj2 = {
    foo: {
        abc: "foo.abc",
    },
    bar: {
        aaa: {
            ccc: "bar.aaa.ccc" // <-- difference
        }
    }
};
```

```js
// function should return true if properties are identical, false otherwise
function compareObjProps(obj1, obj2) {
    for(var prop in obj1) {

        // when comparing bar.aaa.bbb and bar.aaa.ccc
        // this does get logged, but the function doesn't return false
        if(!obj2.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            console.log("mismatch found");
            return false;
        }

        if(typeof(obj1[prop]) === "object") {
            compareObjProps(obj1[prop], obj2[prop]);
        }
    }

    // this always returns
    return true;
}
```

It seems that `return false` does not return from the top level function, but the recursive one.

So how can I return false when the whole matching function is done executing?

Comment: How do you know it diesn't return false? do you evalute the return value?

Comment: @MeNoMore `var result = compareObjPros(obj1, obj2); console.log(result);` always true...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a return:

```
    if(typeof(obj1[prop]) === "object"
        && !compareObjProps(obj1[prop], obj2[prop]))
    {
       return false;
    }
```

Otherwise the result of recursive calls are going to be completely ignored.

Comment: I think you mean that return should happen when recursive call returns false (see edit)...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Yes. I was actually thinking in terms of a path instead of a property tree. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: nah...none of your first or edited version returns false. true still... am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function compareObjProps(obj1, obj2) {
    var result = true;
    for (var prop in obj1) {
        if (obj1.hasOwnProperty(prop) && !obj2.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            console.log("mismatch found");
            result = false;
        } else if (typeof(obj1[prop]) === "object") {
            result = compareObjProps(obj1[prop], obj2[prop]);
        }

        if (!result) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gSYfy/4/

Comment: That worked. I was doing the same by adding a variable to track the result, but didn't succeed. Thanks lan.

Comment: @user1643156 Awesome, glad it worked/helped. Make sure you test it to verify it works fully, although it seems fine. Let me know if you encounter anything!

Comment: sorry lan but I had to take Zeta's answer as accepted since it doesn't require an extra variable. thanks anyway.

Comment: @user1643156 No problem. I'm not sure it would be a good solution if you ever wanted to expand this recursion to do more, but as long as you got something to work, that's great!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a function A called by function B cannot tell B to return. Some people have suggested returning the result of the recursive call, but that wouldn't give you the right result, as it would cause the program to return whether the first sub-object it found was identical, and not if all the objects are identical. I suggest you make this modification:

```
if(typeof(obj1[prop]) === "object") {
   if(!compareObjProps(obj1[prop], obj2[prop])){
      return false;
   }
}
```

This will make your program propagate a "false" as you wanted, but make it keep going if the result was "true".

Comment: HEYHEYHEY...who downvoted this answer? there might be something improper in the explanation. but the code it does work!